# WSO2 EI 6.4.0 warning messages

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, ei, wso2-esb

When I start load test then warning messages shows in EI log.

```
WARN - TargetHandler http-outgoing-519: Request not started while the handler is in an inconsistent state RESPONSE_DONE
WARN - SynapseCallbackReceiver Synapse received a response for the request with message Id : urn:uuid:38d9964b-4fec-4989-ae32-957f9636fa52 But a callback is not registered (anymore) to process this response
```

These warnings shows when call mediators call backend.
That can't be timeout becouse fault sequnece is no called.

Single invocation does not generate these warnings. Warnings only appear under load test.

How can I do to solve these warnings?

EDIT:
I log message:
2020-12-17 12:06:35,671 - call backend
2020-12-17 12:06:35,681 - warn
2020-12-17 12:06:35,706 - response from backend

after warnings, message is further processed correctly

Answer (score 0):

The explanation for the below WARN message.

```
WARN - SynapseCallbackReceiver Synapse received a response for the request with message Id : urn:uuid:38d9964b-4fec-4989-ae32-957f9636fa52 But a callback is not registered (anymore) to process this response
```

In the WSO2 EI, the requests are handled through the PassThrough Transport in an asynchronous manner. Let's say the EI server received a request. Then a single thread is used to serve the request and perform the mediation. Before the request is sent to the external back end, a callback is registered in the callback store and the thread is released to the thread pool. When the response is received for the particular request, another thread is used to correlate the callback and handle the response. the call back is cleared from the callback store if the response is received or after the endpoint timeout.

If the response is received after time out(due to the slowness of the back end), above WARN message is logged since the callback is not available in the callback store.

I assume that your back end is getting slower with the load. You can check this by directly hitting a load on the back end service.

It seems that the other WARN message is logged due to an inconsistency of the sate machine in EI[1]. If you can, share the complete synapse configs related to flow.

[1] https://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/04/demystifying-wso2-esb-pass-through-transport-part-iii

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Backend seems ok. When backend not respond in time defined in endpoint definition, then I see timeout in logs. What is strange to me, is that even when i got warn, respons is received and correctly processing. What do you mean by complete synapse configs related to flow?

Comment: I don't think that the responses are processed after the endpoint timeout. In the EI, there is a timeout handler which runs on every 15sec(default value) interval to detect endpoint timeouts and remove the callback. If the endpoint timeout log is printed in the log, there is no callback for the particular request any more. If the response is received after the timeout, the above-explained warn message is printed in the logs.

Comment: synapse configuration means your proxy service, API, sequences etc.

Comment: Sorry, I can't share synapse configs. If you want, I can show you a simplified message flow diagram. I agree, after endpoint timeout response is not processed and I see log with information about endpoint timeout and then fault sequence is calling. But when these 2 warns are showing then information about timeout is not showing in log, fault sequence is not calling and after these warns response is processing. I seted assertions in load test and I got correctly responses.